# Element {} item is invalid Can anyone explain this error?

Tags: soap, php

When we are connecting to sfdc from php using the SOAP API we are receiving an error message:  ***Element {} item is invalid***   How can i resolve my issuse

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
ini_set(E_ALL,1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);


// Include the PHP Toolkit
require_once('salesforceAPI/soapclient/SforcePartnerClient.php');
require_once('salesforceAPI/soapclient/SforceHeaderOptions.php');

// Login
define('USER','xxxxx@sfdc.com');
define('PASSWORD', 'yyyyyyyy');
define('SECURITY_KEY', 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz');

//echo userName;
//echo password;
//echo securitytoken;

$sfdc = new SforcePartnerClient();
$SoapClient = $sfdc->createConnection('salesforceAPI/partner.wsdl.xml');

$loginResult = false;

try {
    // log in with username, password and security token if required
   $loginResult = $sfdc->login(USER, PASSWORD . SECURITY_KEY);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    global $errors;
    $errors = $e->faultstring;
    echo "Fatal Login Error <b>" . $errors . "</b>";
    die;
}

// Define constants for the web service. We'll use these later
$parsedURL = parse_url($sfdc->getLocation());
define ("_SFDC_SERVER_", substr($parsedURL['host'],0,strpos($parsedURL['host'], '.')));
define ("_WS_NAME_", 'salesforceAPI/Ctest');
define ("_WS_WSDL_", _WS_NAME_ . '.xml');
define ("_WS_ENDPOINT_", 'https://' . _SFDC_SERVER_ . '.salesforce.com/services/wsdl/class/' . _WS_NAME_);
define ("_WS_NAMESPACE_", 'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/' . _WS_NAME_);

$client = new SoapClient(_WS_WSDL_);
$sforce_header = new SoapHeader(_WS_NAMESPACE_, "SessionHeader", array("sessionId" => $sfdc->getSessionId()));
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($sforce_header));

$method = $client->__getFunctions();
echo _SFDC_SERVER_."<br>";
echo _WS_NAME_."<br>";
echo _WS_WSDL_."<br>";
echo _WS_ENDPOINT_."<br>";
echo _WS_NAMESPACE_."<br>";
//
try {

    $wsParams=array('name' =>'hhhi');
    // call the web service via post
    $client->cInsert($wsParams);

// this is really bad.
} catch (Exception $e) {
    global $errors;
    $errors = $e->faultstring;
    echo "Ooop! Error: <b>" . $errors . "</b>";
    die;
}
```

The web service class in question is:

```
global class Ctest {
  // Request Class
  global class RequestClass {
    webservice String accName;
    //webservice String accNum;
  }
  // Response
  Class global class ResponseClass {
    webservice String acName;
  }

  // webservice
  static ResponseClass cInsert(RequestClass req) {
    ResponseClass res = new ResponseClass();
    Account a = new Account();
    a.Name = req.accName;
    insert a;
    res.acName = a.Name;
    return res;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well done, Simon Lawrence. I was just about to make that edit. Sathya, you'd be well advised to not post real UID /Passwords in your code examples in the future. I'm not sure they were, but they looked real enough to tempt a troll to give it a go.

Comment: @Peter sure unexpectedly it done..thanq for edit.but Np they are not real user names and passwords.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possibly because in your php class, you are setting up the web service call with

```
$wsParams=array('name' =>'hhhi');
```

but your request class parameter is called `accName`, when you then try to extract it with

```
a.Name = req.accName;
```

It's been a long time since I worked with PHP.

Comment: $wsParams=array('name' =>'hhhi'); in php code i want to replace 'name' with accname ..??

Comment: I would try it, yes?!
$wsParams=array('accName' =>'hhhi');

Comment: I tried with accName but it showing same error

Comment: I tried as per u r suggestion i cahnged the 'name' to 'accName' but i am getting the same error May i know how can i resolve it

Comment: I'm afraid I can't debug this for you, it's been too long since I worked on PHP and there are a huge amount of possibilities to consider. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This error generally occurs when your variables are null, or invalid. What's happening is the soap envelope is being sent with null parameters, or in this case with an empty body.

I suspect that your USER, PASSWORD and SECURITY_KEY are not available to the $sfdc->login call .

Comment: may i know what i want to do.shall i share my webservice class.

Comment: Feel free to paste a link to a gist of your php code, but please understand I may not be able to help you. It would behove you to try and hard-code the login credentials temporarily like this:

$loginResult = $sfdc->login('your_username_here', 'password_and_security_token_here');

Comment: may i know this error is belongs to php side or sfdc side above is my webservice

Comment: This error is, I believe, in your php code.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when connecting to an Apex Webservice where my endpoint and namespace did not match. I had created a new endpoint, but did not update my client's instantiation.

In other words, I was instantiating a non-existent class (for the given WSDL / namespace). So, in your case, `_WS_NAME_` probably doesn't exist on `_SFDC_SERVER_`? Maybe your partner.wsdl is pointing to the wrong environment? e.g. login.salesforce instead of test.salesforce

Is this the case for you? Hard to know without digging into your WSDL as well as your Apex classes. This answer helped point me in the right direction though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24069746/1135138